# Why does MAGES. say "music animation game event school" backwords?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia

In *Hyperdimesion Neptunia Re;Birth*, when the party does their first job for Avanir in Lastation, they come across MAGES. When the party is unable to help her find "Doc P", she calls someone and at the end of her call she says

> I bid you luck. Loochs tneve emag noitamina cisum.

If we reverse the last part, it says:

> music animation game event schooL

I know that MAGES. is a reference to the parent company of [5pb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5pb.) which is also called [MAGES](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAGES.) (Japanese Wikipedia Page), and I remember reading before the release of *Hyperdimension Neptunia Victory* that her design was inspired by *Steins;Gate*

Why does MAGES. say "music animation game event school" backwards? Is this some reference to one of 5pb's or MAGES' works? (like *Steins;Gate* or other titles in the Science Adventure Series)

Comment: It's probably a reference to El Psy Congroo by Okabe, but I'm not sure since I'm not familiar with the rest of 5pb/MAGES' works.

Comment: Those words spell out MAGES if you take the first letters from each

Comment: Actually if you reverse it, it says Music Animation Game Event **Shcool**.

Comment: look at her name its like MAGES.M as in music. A as in animatoin. G as in Games. E as in event. S as in school.SEE BOOM